# Get a property from a javaBean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans

I have an applicationScoped bean where I initialize my Store.

```
@ManagedBean(name="applicationBean", eager=true)
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class applicationBean implements Serializable {

     private Store store;

        public applicationBean() {
            store = new Store();
        }

        public Store getStore() {
            return store;
        }  

    }
```

An now I want to get my store in my other Bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="productsBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ProductsBean implements Serializable {

    private List <Product> products;

    public ProductsBean(){

    }

}
```

How can I call the getter from my applicationScoped Bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inject your `@ApplicationScoped` bean into ProductsBean as a managed property. Then you will be able to access Store property.

```
@ManagedBean(name="productsBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ProductsBean implements Serializable {

private List <Product> products;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{applicationBean}")
private applicationBean appBean;

public ProductsBean(){

}

}
```

Remember to write a setter for the property, for JSF to be able to set it. And just tell you that class names starting with lowercases (applicationBean) are discouraged in Java language.